# How to change the window icon of a JPackage app on Windows?

Tags: windows, javafx, jlink, jpackage

I'm deploying a self-contained application with JPackage. This is how I compile it for Windows:

```
call "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\jpackage" ^
  --type %INSTALLER_TYPE% ^
  --dest target/installer ^
  --input target/installer/input/libs ^
  --name Deshopp ^
  --main-class com.app.AppLauncher ^
  --main-jar %MAIN_JAR% ^
  --java-options -Xmx2048m ^
  --runtime-image target/java-runtime ^
  --app-version %APP_VERSION% ^
  --icon src/main/logo/windows/logo.ico ^
  --vendor "ACME Inc." ^
  --copyright "Copyright © 2019-20 ACME Inc." ^
  --win-dir-chooser ^
  --win-shortcut ^
  --win-per-user-install ^
  --win-menu
```

But how do I use a custom icon for the application header/window, instead of Windows' default one depicted below?

[image: Screenshot depicting the app's header with a Windows default icon]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the platform specific icon which you specify in the jpackage call, you also have to specify icons in the start method of your main class like this

```
primaryStage.getIcons().addAll(icon16, icon32, icon64, icon128);
```

where icon16, ... are icons for your application with the corresponding sizes.

Comment: icon16 ... are instances of Image, so the original icon can be anything you can load into an image. Normally PNGs are used for this purpose.